# HTML / CSS: Set Div Height and Width to a Multiple of a Tile?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a Div that has a 32x32 tileset as a background-image. I want its minimum Height to be at least 80% of the viewport and its Width around 20% of the viewport, but I want the Height and Width to be a multiple of 32 so that none of the tiles get cut off. Is there a way to have the Div fulfill both of these conditions without hard-coding it? I want to avoid hard-coding these values because the viewport's size changes depending on what computer, tablet, or phone you view it on.

I'm a beginner in HTML / CSS, so I don't know a lot of the tools that are available. Any help would be appreciated! (Edited to add code snippet.)

```
/* Note: tower-sides.png is a 32x32 png with no transparency. */

/* Sidebar Tileset*/
--sidebarimg: url("/assets/main/img/tower-sides.png");

/* This section handles the Sidebars */
aside{
   width: 20%;
   background-color: var(--sidebarbg);
   background-image: var(--sidebarimg);
   font-size: smaller;
}
#left-sidebar{order: 1;}
#right-sidebar{order: 3;}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat#values (look at the space and round values)

Comment: The space and round values don't do quite what I want. Space would add unwanted whitespace in my divs, and round would stretch the tileset in an unpleasant way.

Comment: I suggest you add a simple code snippet, so people could have a more concrete understanding of the context and better answer your question.

Comment: @spriterjohnson In CSS, division without a remainder has not yet been introduced (but work in this direction is underway). But there is no problem calculating the block size in js. First, find out how many pixels make up 80%/20% of the viewport. Then divide by 32, discarding the fractional part, and multiply the resulting result by 32 and write it down to the height/width of your block.

Comment: @AndreiFedorov: Wouldn't hardcoding the Height and Width of the Divs that way mean that other viewports (mobile phones, other computers, etc.) either cut off information or have extra whitespace?

Comment: `I want its Height at / around 80% and its Width at / around 20%` what does this mean? What is `height at / around 80%`?

Comment: @RonnieRoyston: By "at / around 80%," I mean that I want the height of the Div to be at least 80% of the viewport. It doesn't have to be exact; I'm more concerned that the tileset doesn't get cut off and doesn't get stretched. Since the viewport will have a different height and width depending on the computer, tablet, or phone the website is viewed on, I don't want to hard-code a height and width value.

Comment: Please edit your question to enhance clarity rather than adding a comment that may not be read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## CSS-only solution (lacks browser support)

You can use CSS `round()` to round `20vw` to the nearest `32px`.

**Edit** - you can optionally specify whether you want the `round` CSS function to round `down`, `up`, or `closest`:

```
width: round(down, 20vw, 32px);
height: round(down, 80vh, 32px);
```

So here's how the solution looks:

```css
div {
  background-image: url(https://placehold.co/32);
  
  width: round(nearest, 20vw, 32px);
  height: round(nearest, 80vh, 32px);
  
  outline: 3px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**However note** - as of Nov 2023 only Firefox and Safari support `round()`.

## CSS-only 2

This solution is supported by all major browsers, but will result in large HTML code. Moreover, the effect is purely visual and the actual width of the box will always be `20vw`.

This solution uses css grid with columns of a fixed `32px` size which wrap around responsively. By removing any borders and background on the main box, and putting the background image inside the children of the box, we get this solution:

```css
div {  
  width: 20vw;
  height: 80vh;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fill, 32px );
  grid-template-rows: repeat( auto-fill, 32px );
}
div > span {
  background-image: url(https://placehold.co/32);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
  ... many, many spans ...
  <span></span>
</div>
```

But using this approach is not recommended.

## Using JavaScript

I think the best method is this one - to do exactly what the CSS `round()` function does, but using JavaScript. Ie, resize the container to the nearest `32px`.

In JavaScript, you have to wrap this around a `resize` event listener so it re-adjusts every time the user resizes the viewport.

```js
const div = document.querySelector("div");
function resizeDiv() {
  div.style.width = Math.round(.2*window.innerWidth / 32) * 32 + "px";
  div.style.height = Math.round(.8*window.innerHeigth / 32) * 32 + "px";
}
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeDiv);
resizeDiv();
```

```css
div {  
  width: 20vw;
  height: 80vh;
  min-width: 32px;
  min-height: 32px;
  background-image: url(https://placehold.co/32);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Like with the first solution, you can choose whether to round the width/height down, up, or nearest.

- To round down, use `Math.floor(...)`
- To round up, use `Math.ceil(...)`
- To round to the nearest 32px, use `Math.round(...)` <- this is what the snippet above is using

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm still learning the functions that are available in CSS, so I didn't even know calc() and round() were options. I appreciate it!

Comment: @spriterjohnson yeah, np, i didn't know round existed either until today! Also you might want to check browser support for round(). I think calc() should be good.

Comment: You've missed one of the main benefits of the CSS [`round()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/round), the ability to specify the (optional) "rounding strategy," which allows: `width: round(down, 20vw, 32px);`

Comment: @Krokodil Please clarify in your answer about browser support for `round()`

Comment: @spriterjohnson check my edited answer please for important info. If you'd like a version that is supported by all major browsers, let me know.

Comment: @Krokodil: If you happen to have one that works for all major browsers, I would appreciate it! I happen to be using Firefox, so it works for my purposes, but if this current solution would break for other browsers, then a more general solution would be good to at least know about.

Comment: @spriterjohnson - check the answer now, I've included two more options which have full browser support